# jQuery getScript() vs document.createElement('script')

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic-loading

Assuming that both of these approaches load the script properly, and that I wait the appropriate amount of time before using the script (and/or use a callback), what are the major differences between these approaches.

*Note: I understand the first uses jQuery (which is a larger download etc.). What I'm really interested in is the after affects of these approaches. Does one place the script in a different scope than the other? Etc.*

jQuery:

```
function loadScript() {
    $.getScript('http://www.mydomain/myscript.js');
}
```

Appending to body:

```
function loadScript() {
   var script= document.createElement('script');
   script.type= 'text/javascript';
   script.src= 'http://www.mydomain/myscript.js';
   script.async = true;
   document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Appending to head:

```
function loadScript() {
   var head= document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
   var script= document.createElement('script');
   script.type= 'text/javascript';
   script.src= 'http://www.mydomain/myscript.js';
   script.async = true;
   head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: is there a way on pure javascript to detect when the script is loaded? I mean `jQuery.getScript()` function has a callback... is there something similar in javascript?

Comment: Oh i just thinked a bit on it... maybe `<script onload="myScriptCallback()" src="/pathtoscript.js"></script>` ? What do u think guys?

Comment: would love to know this as well...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery appends the `script` element to `head` if present, or to `document` element otherwise. Under the hood [the code is similar](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/script.js). The final result will be the same: both approaches execute new code in the global scope.

Comment: thanks, my doc will have a `head` so thats where jQuery will append. the question then becomes is there a difference between appending the code to the `head` vs the `body` like my middle example?

Comment: jQuery only appends a <script> tag if the script is loaded from a remote domain (e.g. `http://someothersite.com/script.js`).  If the script is from the local domain (e.g. `/script.js`), then jQuery simply executes it in-memory and never creates a <script> tag

Answer (score 2):

the documentation to Jquery method says:

> Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP request, then execute it.

That means the imported javascript will be straigt invoked after successful loading.

Appending to the head: It means the browser adds the script-tag as a last child and executes the content (it is the same if you add the tag manuelly at the end of the head tag).
Appending to the body: It means the browser adds the script-tag as a last child of the body tag and executes that content (it is the same if you add the tag manuelly at the end of the body tag).

Answer (score 2):

It is worth mentioning that jQuery's `getScript` function disables caching by default, meaning that browsers will download the script every time the page is requested (see previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12885561/2213883)). Your `loadScript` function, on the other hand, should take advantage of caching.