# Full calendar breaks on view switch

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, fullcalendar

Whenever I switch my months on fullcalendar I receive the following error message

```
Uncaught TypeError: specialTokens[fakePart.substring(...)] is not a function
```

and all of my events disappear from the calendar.

I'm trying to re-render my events on month change, but I keep getting the error message and It won't re-load my events.

Javascript

```
var events = <?php echo $eventsArray ?>;
var blocked = <?php echo $blockedArray ?>;
var date = new Date();
var d = date.getDate();
var m = date.getMonth();
var y = date.getFullYear();
console.log(blocked);
for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(blocked).length; i++) {
 console.log(blocked[i].date);
}
$('#democalendarfull').fullCalendar({
 header: {
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
 },
 viewRender: function(view, element) {
  $('#democalendarfull').fullCalendar( 'rerenderEvents' );
 },
  editable: false,
  aspectRatio: 2,
  droppable: false,
  events: events,
  dayRender: function (date, cell) {
  var today = new Date();
   if (date._d.getDate() === today.getDate()) {
    cell.css("background-color", "red");
   }
  }
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="democalendarfull" class="mb">
                  <div class="panel green-panel no-margin">
                      <div class="panel-body">
                          <div id="date-popover" class="popover top" style="cursor: pointer; disadding: block; margin-left: 33%; margin-top: -50px; width: 175px;">
                              <div class="arrow"></div>
                              <h3 class="popover-title" style="disadding: none;"></h3>
                              <div id="date-popover-content" class="popover-content"></div>
                          </div>

                             //JAVASCRIPT IS INSIDE HERE

                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
```

PHP

```
$results= $db->query("SELECT * FROM mytable");
                            $events = array();
                            while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
                              $e = array();
                              $e['id'] = $fetch['id'];
                              $e['title'] = $fetch['title'];
                              $e['start'] = $fetch['start'];
                              $e['end'] = $fetch['end'];
                              $e['url'] = $fetch['url'];
                              array_push($events, $e);
                            }
                            $eventsArray = json_encode($events);
```

My events are all loading and working fine on page load, but as soon as I cycle through the months I receive the error message and it breaks! I don't know whether i'm using it wrong, but no matter what I do I cant get it to keep my events!

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue after upgrading fullCalendar, took me a bit to figure out because for almost a year everything has been working fine and I had upgraded fullCalendar in the past without any issues, for some reason I had to include `moment.js` in the page I was using the fullCalendar on, see I run an MVC site and previously the master page (`_layout.cshtml`) was referencing `moment.js`, not sure right now why that doesn't work anymore, just as a test I added a reference to moment in the actual page I use fullCalendar and the issue I was having with events went away as well as another issue with `undefined` in my calendar title.

In my case the fix was:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/dates")
```

in your case it may just be:

```
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.18.1/moment.min.js'></script>
```

And if your issue isn't the reference to moment you may want to try using call back, the [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/) mentions this but I dont see you using it:

try:

```
callback($events);
```

Comment: My issue was similar, only I was getting the error when I attempted to place the calendar in a Bootstrap modal. Fixed it by loading moment.min.js along with fullcalendar.js each time modal was opened (utilized caching to save on network resources...fullcalendar.js was about 600kb https://stackoverflow.com/a/12885561/2969615 )