# Deleted javascript file still running

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a page with button on it. When click the button jquery start running. It calls a function using ajax. I change the  js file on project and try to see whats happening in localhost but js file is still runs old version before i changed and i can see on page source old version. why i can not change the file?

```
    $(this).click(function (e) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: "test.aspx/function",
            data:  $(this).text(),
            dataType: 'Json',
            success: function (Result) {
                Result = Result.d;
                data = Result;      
            }
        });
    };
```

i want to change data but it still running as above
data: $(this).parent().text(),

Comment: Have you tried to reload the whole page again by pressing `Ctrl` + `F5`

Comment: You need to make a full refresh: ctrl + F5

Comment: I did, even i restart computer and rebuild the project but i didnt change

Comment: Your file properly is still cashed by your browser. As mentioned above, if you refresh the site with `Ctrl + F5` you force your browser to download all files, even if they are already known to you / your browser. Often you can see these files responding with a HTTP 304 (not modified).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to reload the `test.aspx/function` that is ajax called, you can open the [developer tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/inspect-styles/) (right click on page, click on inspect).

After the developer tools have been open, click on reload and keep that click until a menu opens. There click on ["**Hard Reload**"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14969315/whats-the-difference-between-normal-reload-hard-reload-and-empty-cache-a), or even the **Empty Cache and Hard Reload**

[image]

Other way is to use [`cache`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) of  [jQuery ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884097/jquery-getscript-caching/12885561#12885561) call for your tests.

And one other way is to disable the page cache for `test.aspx/function` on code behind. For example add that on your response.

```
    Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(-4));
    Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
```