# How to check if ajax response is javascript content type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have several different forms that each return something different. I need to detect if it's a simple string (so i can put it in the error/status area) or if its javascript I do nothing and let it execute.

This is currently how I'm doing my checking, but I want to make sure this is 100% sturdy and reliable... I couldn't think of any other way.

The other option would be to always use JSON, but then I need a JSON shim, as well as somehow trying to serialize javascript into JSON.

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:  form.attr('action'),
    data: form.serialize()
  })
  .done(function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    if (!xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type').match(/text\/javascript/i)) {
      form.find('.status').text(data).removeClass().addClass('status status-done').slideDown(200);
    } else { 
      // this is where i do nothing and let JS run
    }
  })
```

The following works, but I'm afraid there would be some edge case where it's not going to work (not sure what that might be, but it's important this section works 100%)

Comment: Why do you need a JSON shim? What ancient browsers you need to support? I think you're facing an XY problem here...

Comment: I'd recommend that you read up on ajax dataType's as it appears that you got some bad information.   http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: How should I differentiate between JSON and application/javascript then?

Comment: @Tallboy The server/application should be responding with [`Content-Type: application/json`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477816/what-is-the-correct-json-content-type) or at least similar for JSON. (Unless it's [JSON-P](http://json-p.org/).)

Comment: I know that, but my question revolves around... what is the best way to have my .done() ajax promise determine if the response is application/json (show the error message above the form), or... application/javascript (do nothing and let the JS execute. i dont want to be injecting the response JS into the form so i need to determine the content type)

Comment: Does each POST endpoint return the same content type each time or does it differ? For instance, if the action is "/doSomething" will doSomething always return JavaScript or does it depend on something else?

Comment: well I have 5 forms that all are controlled with 1 ajax function (for simplicity). I have decided to just use json though, without having any JS in the body. Instead is set a few special json properties and then just parse that in the script. My last question is, so my script is safe and jquery is using $.parseJSON right? I dont need any shims?

Comment: If you're using JSON.parse (or parseJSON if you insist on using a library) then it will toss out anything with a function in it. JSON can only contain strings, arrays, numbers and other objects that only contain those things, so yes, you're safe. Hope this helps!

Comment: If interpret Question , determine if response within json reposne `string` ? js not in response ? , only variables as string within json responses ? If response `text/javascript` , jquery ajax create `script` tag , run script , remove script tag ? , `data` not processed through `.done(fn(data){})` ? If possible, can detail requirement ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, Not certain about detail of requirement . If interpret Question correctly , at different `form` elements , different response types from `$.ajax()` requests ? a) Check for response type `string` ? b) do nothing ?

Could possibly check for response type `string` within `json` response with

```
if (typeof data.data === "string") { 
  // do stuff , with `string`
}
```

if `$.ajax()` expect `json` response , receive js , could possible run the piece immediately. At piece below , first response is `string` , filtered through `if` at `.done()` . Second response `json` object having a js function expression as property , which appear to run immediately , at `$.ajax()` `success` `textStatus` . Still capable to check response `type` of `object` at `else` , though , run as `script` . See empty `xhr.repsonseText` and `xhr.reponseJSON` at `console`

Try

```
var urls = [["/echo/json/","abc"]
            , ["/echo/json/",
              {"abc": 
                (function() { 
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        $("body").append("<div id=data>" 
                        + "object" + "</div>"); 
                        $("#data")
                        .hide(0)
                        .fadeIn(1200)},1200) 
                 }())
               }]
            ];


    var request = function(url, _data) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  url,
        data: {json : JSON.stringify({"data":_data})}
      })
      .done(function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
        if (typeof data.data === "string") {
            $("body").append("<div>" + data.data + "</div>")
        } else { 
            console.log(typeof data.data
                        , data
                        , xhr.responseText
                        , xhr.responseJSON);
          // this is where i do nothing and let JS run
        }
      })
    };

    $.each(urls, function(k, v) {
      request(v[0], v[1])
    });
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/y9b7t740/

See

[jQuery getScript() vs document.createElement('script')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5791279/jquery-getscript-vs-document-createelementscript) , [script.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/ajax/script.js)

[Calling a JavaScript function returned from an Ajax response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510779/calling-a-javascript-function-returned-from-an-ajax-response)

[jQuery: Evaluate script in ajax response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158075/jquery-evaluate-script-in-ajax-response)

[What is JSONP all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about)